# how to bundle Java application and Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, swing, oracle10g, awt

I created one small application in java. And I used Oracle as database. Now I want to create one exe file so that I can transfer my application to other pc. But I am unable to understand how to add database files to my application. I am able to create executable jar file, but it doesn't have the database structure and Oracle installation is required to use my application. Is there any platform required to install, to work with Oracle database without actual Oracle installation as like jre for java? And how I bundle the application and database together?

Comment: You have not provided much information. It's too broad/unclear.

Comment: Bundling a database with an application makes sense only if you're using an in-memory database. Bundling Oracle with your small application is a ridiculous idea.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.can you please tell me the solution for this. Then what should I use to save my application data? And how to take backup of that data?

Comment: @user6725738 please do not put your question in the answers section. And when you reply to a **comment** try using @ username so that the person in interest will be notified. Having said all that ... Oracle isn't going to work the way you are describing (bundled with the application) - check out my answer below....

Answer (score 0):

Try using something else for local storage like [JAVADB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) also [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javadb-141163.html)
or maybe [sqlLite](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm)